# How to get all the active directory users and groups in SharePoint using C# SSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, ssom

I have two dropdown list in one of my custom webpart. I want to load all users and groups from an active directory into respective dropdown list on a form. I am making use of SSOM for developing a registration form which includes these two dropdown list. 
DropdownUSER will load all users from Active Directory and
DropdownGroup will load all groups available in that AD.

Answer (score 1):

I have article where I discussed how to get all users under a particular group or OU. Try it out from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1029168/How-to-Synchronize-Active-Directory-Users-to-a-Sha)

```
using (var directoryInfo = new DirectoryEntry(SyncPath, UserName, Password))
            {
                var userFindingfilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
                var userProperties = new string[] { "title", "whenChanged", "displayName", "department", "sAMAccountName", "userPrincipalName", "manager" };
                using (var directoryInfoSearch = new DirectorySearcher(directoryInfo, userFindingfilter, userProperties, SearchScope.Subtree))
                {
                    var directoryEntryUserSearchResults = directoryInfoSearch.FindAll();
                    foreach (SearchResult searchResult in directoryEntryUserSearchResults)
                    {
                        var searchResultDirectoryEntry = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                        if (searchResultDirectoryEntry.Properties["manager"].Value == null)
                            continue;
                        var managerDnName = searchResultDirectoryEntry.Properties["manager"].Value.ToString();
                        var manager = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + managerDnName);
                        SaveItemIfNotExists(searchResultDirectoryEntry, manager);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint SSOM does not have methods like that. You should use `System.DirectoryServices` or `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespaces instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FindAll() method of the [PrincipalSearcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalsearcher.aspx) Class in the [System.DirectoryServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481534%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here is a sample:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com"))
        {
            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
            {
                foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                {
                    DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                    DropDownUsers.Items.Add(de.Properties["givenName"].Value + " " + de.Properties["sn"].Value);

                }
            }
        }
```

givenName will give you the First Name and sn will give you the Last Name